# Do the idempotents lift mod $J(R)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit element such that any ideal is decomposed as a sum of an idempotent ideal and a small ideal (i.e., an ideal in the Jacobson radical $J(R)$). I want to know whether the idempotents of $R/J(R)$ lift mod $J(R)$, i.e., if $x^2-x\in J(R)$ for $x\in R$, do we have $x-e\in J(R)$ for an idempotent $e\in R$ ?

From the hypothesis we get that any ideal of $R/J(R)$ would be idempotent, so it is a von Neumann regular ring. So, for $x\in R$, there exists $y\in R$ with $x-xyx=x-x^2y\in J(R)$. Now, if  $x^2-x\in J(R)$, then $x^2y-xy\in J(R)$ from which  we deduce that $x-xy\in J(R)$. If we could be assured that $xy$ is an idempotent we would be through.

Any suggestion and/or help is welcome.

Comment: In Artinian rings idempotents lift modulo Jacobson radical. See Rotman's an introduction to homological algebra  (second edition 2008) Proposition 4.53.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general. Consider the localization of the ring of integers at prime ideals generated by 3 and 5.